# Using custom Xon/Xoff characters with pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial

Is it possible to redefine the "constants" serial.XON and serial.XOFF.  I'm assuming that if the underlying uart supports xon/xoff flow control in the hardware then pyserial passes these constants down the driver chain.  I know I can get around this by turning off xon/xoff flow control and processing the chars myself.  I already do that to wait for the Xon char which my application requires.  Which is interfacing to weird serial protocols on cnc machines.  But I would like the uart to do it if possible.  CNC machines are very sensitive to buffer overflows.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm currently investigating using the mrpog [link](http://mprog.software.informer.com/3.5/) program to re-program the FTDI chips in my serial adapters.  It might solve this problem and another I have.  Of course this won't help with cheap knockoffs that don't use FTDI

Comment: Using the ftdi chip programmer is of no value in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually nothing to stop you doing this:

```
import serial
serial.XON = chr(100)
serial.XOFF = chr(101)
```

Obviously you'd use your own values instead of `100` and `101`. But there's no guaranteee that the serial module will be using XON and XOFF internally, so you would be best to experiment to ensure that it works as you want.

Comment: Well I was able to redieine the "constant".  Who would thunk that was possible?  But it didn't work.  Thanks anyway.